# API 2.0 how to upload file with POSTMAN?

Tags: box-api

I'm reading API 2.0 documentation and try using POSTMAN (recommended in the documentation).

In "[Upload a file](http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-upload-a-file)" section, I got "404 not found" error.

for example:

{"type":"error","status":404,"code":"not_found","help_url":"","message":"Unknown Error","request_id":"11139828924fa91c0d283d2"}

POSTMAN window image is [here](https://www.box.com/s/6d8b00d9d1cbe2f615fe).
Base URL is tring "upload.box.com/api/2.0" (temporary, according to the document).

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain specific Upload issues have all been resolved. You can now direct all API requests, including uploads, to https://api.box.com/2.0

Comment: Because of API document: "Alert: We’re experiencing a temporary bug with uploads at api.box.com. Please temporarily use https://upload.box.com/api/2.0 as a base URL for uploads."

Comment: OK. I understand what you mean.

Upload complete by using "https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/data".

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not that this is no longer the recommend method, and https://api.box.com/2.0 is once again the recommend base URL.

Answer (score 2):

One more point, your POSTMAN request misses to indicate `folder_id` in its form data . You need that "`folder_id`" value for the request to work .